# How can I tell what app an Erlang module belongs to based on the OTP docs?

Tags: erlang

How can I tell which app an Erlang module belongs to, based on the docs?

For example, is [public_key](https://erlang.org/doc/man/public_key.html) part of kernel, or is it part of stdlib, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in the top left corner of the documentation page:

[image: lists module documentation, part of stdlib application]

Here we see that the `lists` module is part of the `stdlib` application.

This also applies to `public_key`: the `public_key` module is the only documented module of the `public_key` application.

Answer (score 4):

When I click on the link you provided, I see:

[image]